# Play video files in a local Lan folder with KDE

Tags: video, networking, kubuntu, directory, playback

I'm trying to play video files in a LAN network folder from within dolphin. 
These are Samba folders which I can access, delete files and write and copy from. 
The same video files play perfectly with any video player when I copy them to my local folder beforehand.

Any help?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Ok everybody, now I found out whats up: Like "ClashTheBunny" pointed out Dolphin feeds the link to vlc - so to access the file you have to open VLC preferences > show all > input/codecs  > access modules > smb and enter your smb browsing credentials (smb user/password). I left the domain blank because I use the standard workgroup browsing... 
works like a charme!

Comment: sry for answering myself, but it seems this is really the way to go! thx anyways for all efforts!

Answer (score 2):

Dolphin's interface is feeding VLC a file as far as I know.  Have you tried bumping up the cache for the file input plugin?

Tools -> Preferences -> Choose "All" in "Show Settings" -> Input / Codecs -> Access Modules -> File -> Caching value (ms) -> 3000 or 6000 or 12000

Also bump up the network cache value.

If it is getting passed an SMB uri, which I doubt it is, try this:

Tools -> Preferences -> Choose "All" in "Show Settings" -> Input / Codecs -> Access Modules -> SMB -> Caching value in ms -> 3000 or 6000 or 12000

Comment: sry, but has nothing to do with caching, the error message is it can't open "smb://server/videos/tutorials/topic", though I've set the user/password in the SMB access module ...

Answer (score 1):

I don't use KDE but would like to do make a suggestion:

if you can copy the url from within dolphin and open it with a media player, would that work for you? is so i will give example for VLC

- open vlc
- advanced open file (ctrl+shift+o)
- open the tab "network"
- enter the URL which should look something like smb://yourmachine/videos/todaysvideo/intereresting_movie.avi

caveats:

1. This solution does not work from within dolphin as you requested
2. it probably does not work if you have to login to have access to the file (but maybe you can (temporarily) lower these restrictions)

Comment: Thx for your suggestion. But I have a few hundred small video tutorials (chapters) to be accessed by 4 (soon maybe 6) kubuntu boxes. I can set up the default player on the machines but your solution wouldn't work conveniently. A static /etc/fstab solution won't work work either cause more videos are created and shared via more shared folders ...

Answer (score 1):

Mediatomb could be used to host the files over UPnP. The files could then be accessed with something like XBMC (you can add UPnP shares as a video folder). It's a bit of an overkill but I use such setup at home to view movies from different machines, and all files are stored on a server.

You could also just set up a Dropbox share between the boxes, as I recall, it attempt to serve files via LAN before resorting to WAN.

Edit: I see you edited your question and now mentioned Samba. XBMC also works with samba shares if I recall correctly. In any case, you could mount those Samba shares on the other boxes with (I think) FUSE.

Answer (score 1):

There is a way to open video files on SMB network using "nautilus" of gnome/Unity.
After install nautilus, run KDE->type "nautilus" and Run nautilus.
(Or make shortcut for nautilus.)

There are some merits for using nautilus, first merit is it can be played just double click video files on two or more SMB network what has different user / password. No need to set user/password to VLC SMB setting, just need to login on nautilus access to target folder, and it can be remembered.
(Even the filepath / filename has CJK characters, it can be played. :-) )

Second merit is some other players not support network option can be play on network file without copying target files to local temporary folder, because natilus automatically mount SMB network.

I'm using Unity and KDE. Sometimes KDE package good for me, the other times Unity(gnome) package good for me. 
I think it is better that choose good programs for purpose each time.
(Not only KDE, not only Unity)

Answer (score 0):

You can use Smb4k

[Application pic](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Rq8lY.png)

I did the following in a fresh install of kUbuntu 14.04.4 LTS

```
sudo apt-get install smb4k
```

1. Go to application launcher and type smb4k, then click or enter to run.
2. Click on the tab at the bottom left that says “Network Neighborhood”
3. Browse for your network shares (windows, smb/samba, etc). My shares
   are username/password protected so when I tried to access them, it
   prompted me for login details and after entering them the shares
   were automatically mounted.
4. After it’s mounted, you can use the default file manager (Dolphin)
   to browse, access files, play movies, etc.

More info on Smb4k at [kde-apps.org](http://kde-apps.org/content/show.php?content=9814&forumpage=5), userbase.kde.org/Smb4K or go to docs.kde.org and type smb4k in application name.